# Select most recent date per group but grouping must be done on consecutive dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

How can I group adjacent rows by one column values, so only most recent of those grouped rows is returned?

*Data inside `travel` table*

```
id   name    location    date
--------------------------------------------
1    name    London      2018-09-01 00:00:00
2    name    London      2018-09-02 00:00:00
3    name    NYC         2018-09-03 00:00:00
4    name    London      2018-09-04 00:00:00
5    name    NYC         2018-09-05 00:00:00
6    name    NYC         2018-09-06 00:00:00
7    name    Tokyo       2018-09-07 00:00:00
```

*Result (with order reversed)*

```
7    name    Tokyo       2018-09-07 00:00:00
6    name    NYC         2018-09-06 00:00:00
4    name    London      2018-09-04 00:00:00
3    name    NYC         2018-09-03 00:00:00
2    name    London      2018-09-02 00:00:00
```

Fiddle to play around with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02033ba/15

Comment: Is it possible to have _more than two_ consecutive rows with same location?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, and it will 100% occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double `NOT EXISTS`. Simply put, select all rows except those where same location exists in the future and a different location does not exist in between.

```
SELECT *
FROM travel curr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM travel next
    WHERE next.name = curr.name
    AND next.location = curr.location
    AND next.date > curr.date
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM travel inbw
        WHERE inbw.name = curr.name
        AND inbw.location <> curr.location
        AND inbw.date > curr.date
        AND inbw.date < next.date
    )
)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

[Revised SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02033ba/17)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is like an "Inception" movie :) And works exactly how I need it.